# Is there a text-to-speech system for Ubuntu which can do 'character' voices?

Tags: text-to-speech

Most people are looking for natural sounding TTS.  I am looking for something that has personality for an animatronic creature. It could be robotic or gruff or babyish, but it should be amusing.

Comment: Perhaps you could run your text to speech in a normal voice and then run that through Audacity: https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-amazing-sound-fx-can-make-audacity/

Comment: Thanks.  I'd thought of using sound distortion on top of conventional TTS, but I did not know of a free program that could do that.

Comment: I would like to hear the results of your quest.

Comment: I could not find anything.  The best solution appears to be to use voice distortion after normal TTS.  It probably only works for robotic type characters.